# Solve $\min_{\bf x}\|{\bf Ax}\|$, s.t. $\|{\bf x}\|=1$ and ${\bf Bx}\geq 0$

Tags: least-squares, svd, constraints

I would like to solve a homogeneous least squares problem (i.e. a linear least squares problem where the constants are all zero but where I want to avoid the trivial zero solution). The usual form of these problems:

$\min_{\bf x} \|{\bf Ax}\|$, s.t. $\|{\bf x}\|=1$

can be solved by taking the SVD of ${\bf A}$ and the solution is given by the last column of the matrix ${\bf V}$ from the SVD. However, I am interested in solving a constrained version of this problem, namely:

$\min_{\bf x} \|{\bf Ax}\|$, s.t. $\|{\bf x}\|=1$ and ${\bf Bx}\geq 0$

Is there a closed form solution to this problem?

Comment: please, write $||Ax||^2$ and $||x||^2=1$ instead of $|.|$. and decomposing $x$ on the singular vectors of $A$ will let the solution appear

Comment: Squaring the norms wouldn't change the solution though would it? I've edited to use the correct norm notation. If I take the SVD of A, how does that ensure that constraints contained in B are satisfied?

Comment: Is this still relevant? Could the constraint $ {x}^{T} x = 1 $ be relaxed into $ {x}^{T} x \leq 1 $?